# How to allow forms(pdf) to be re-editable after they have been saved(Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, pdf, save, core-graphics, editing

I'm new to CoreGraphics framework.
We have used ILPDFKit library to render PDF or form
We embedded the drawn paths to existing PDF.Here is the code

```
-(NSData *)embededPdfAnnotationPointsInPdfAtPath:(NSString *)pdfPath
{
    NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil);

    for(NSUInteger pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= [self pdfDrawViewInfo].count; pageIndex ++)
    {
        //  Get the current page and page frame
        CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageIndex);
        const CGRect pageFrame = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame, nil);

        //  Draw the page (flipped)
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -pageFrame.size.height);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

        UIImage *drawViewImage = [self annotatedImageForPdfPageAtIndex:(pageIndex - 1)];
        UIImage *annotatedImgForPdfPage = [self imageWithImage:drawViewImage scaledToSize:pageFrame.size] ;
        [annotatedImgForPdfPage drawInRect:pageFrame];
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
//    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
//    CGImageRelease(annotatedImgCGref);

    return data;
}
```

Above code indicates, we are just pasting image(drawn paths) on existing PDF.

Later functionality changed as "After saving PDF with annotations(freehand drawing), we need to have control over annotated stuff"

**Question:**
Edit PDF with annotation(freehand drawing), save it.After saving the PDF with annotated stuff, we need to again gain its editing capability. We need to know the saving mechanism and steps of this process.Please put your views here, so that it help me a lot.

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

I would probably conserve the pdf original version, and store the edits in another file.

Than each time the user save, the app apply the annotations and other stuff to original version and generate the final pdf (in case of sharing or exportation features)

That would give you a complete control, (i guess this is also the same way "apple photo", "iPhoto" and "Aperture" manage the pictures modifications...)

Comment: Thanks for support.
Store the edits in another file.Can u please elaborate the steps.